# Ubuntu apps cant detect wifi interface

Tags: wireless, interface

Wifite and linset or fluxion master cannot detect wifi interface. My wifi card is connecting to network. But not detected by scripts and application.

Here is the `lshw -C network` result

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 11
       serial: 9c:5c:8e:8f:73:99
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:5
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:1e:a6:90:6b:bf
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192eu ip=192.168.1.7 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

this is my kernel version

```
#37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016
```

Comment: May you please edit your answer with the results of "lshw -C network"?

Comment: What is the output to `uname --kernel-version`?

Comment: sorry @PatrickNegus